# Syntax error in setting unused column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have a table named `e_emp3` in Oracle with these fields among others:

- FNAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
- SAL   NUMBER(8,2)
- DEPTNO    NUMBER(4,0)

I need to alter `e_emp3` and set unused column(sal) with online keyword to stay dml operations for users on this table. I wrote this code:

```
alter table e_emp3 set unused(sal) online;
```

but I got the following error message

[image]

Please help me what is problem? When I run this code without online keyword it succeeds. When I add online keyword it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you mark a column `unusued`, there is no way back, just restore from backup.

[Dropping Table Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11663)

> **Removing Unused Columns**
>
> The ALTER TABLE...DROP UNUSED COLUMNS statement is the only action
>   allowed on unused columns. It physically removes unused columns from
>   the table and reclaims disk space.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2124702)

the `set unused` clause does not support the `online` keyword:

[image: set unused]

As you can see in the syntax diagram, you can only use `cascade constraints` or `invalidate`

---

The `online` option is only valid for the [move_table_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2081902)

[image: move_table_clause]